# Classify column with URLs into categories base on terms

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm still a newbie in Python and having a hard time trying to code something.

I have a list with more than 80k URLs and this is the only thing I have in my .xls, the URLs looks like this:

```
https://domainexample.com/user-query/credit-card-debit-balance/
https://domainexample.com/user-query/second-invoice-current-debt/
https://domainexample.com/user-query/query-balances/
https://domainexample.com/user-query/where-is-client-portal/
https://domainexample.com/user-query/i-want-to-change-my-password/
https://domainexample.com/user-query/second-invoice-internet/
https://domainexample.com/user-query/print-payment-invoice/
```

I want to create a code that will read this excel and based on certain categories I already wrote, will put them in other columns.

So, whenever the code finds "paswword" it will put that URL in the column password,  when it finds "user" will put the URL in the column "user".

It would look like this:

```
debt
https://domainexample.com/user-query/second-invoice-current-debt/

password
https://domainexample.com/user-query/i-want-to-change-my-password/

payment
https://domainexample.com/user-query/print-payment-invoice/
```

The code doesn't necessarily needs to change the column of the URLs, if it can create a 2nd column and write of what categories that URL belongs, it would be also great.

There is no need for the code to read the URL, just the excel file, like those URLs are simple text.

If anyone can help me, thanks a lot!

Comment: I am a bit confused. Do all the url have vehicle in the end like in the example?

Comment: No, unfortunately no. The domain is the same for all URLs, but the path is different for every single one of them.

But whenever it has "car" I know that its for the category car, when it has "bike" is for bikes" when it has "How" is for questions, and another parameters I will list.

Comment: Okay. Would be nice if could share some real data.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Grayrigel!

Here are some URL examples:

https://domainexample.com/user-query/credit-card-debit-balance/
https://domainexample.com/user-query/second-invoice-current-debt/
https://domainexample.com/user-query/query -balances/
https://domainexample.com/user-query/where-is-client-portal/
https://domainexample.com/user-query/i-want-to-change-my-password/
https://domainexample.com/user-query/second-invoice-internet/
https://domainexample.com/user-query/print-payment-invoice/

I'm editing the main topic with these.

Comment: Oh. I see. you want to scrape the data into the urls iteself because vehicle have no information regarding the urls. You might wanna look at `Selenium` or `BeautifulSoup`. I could try but i am seeing malicious warnings from firefox.

Comment: No @Grayrigel, those terms like "cars", "bike" and "van" are merely for example and there is no need to scrap data into the url.

You saw that many URLs have terms like "payment" or "passwords" and thinks like this, I will list all of these terms and then instruct Python to "when the url has the term passwords, put it in this column", "when it has payment, put in this column". Not needing to parse and read the url, just the terms that are in the url.

Comment: did you manage solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this where df is your dataframe, and 'url_column' is the column with all your urls

```
df.loc[df['url_column'] =='url.com/what-is-a-car', 'car'] = 'url.com/'+'car'
df.loc[df['url_column'] =='url.com/what-is-a-bike', 'bike'] = 'url.com/'+'bike'
df.loc[df['url_column'] =='url.com/what-is-a-van', 'van'] = 'url.com/'+'van'
```

Comment: Hello, Brian. Thanks for the comment! The problem is that i have more than 80k URLs, and by what you are saying I would have to list all of them?

Comment: How many car, bike, van categories do you have?  Do you have an approximate amount?  It should be able to do 80k rows.

Comment: Unfortunate no, I have no idea. And probably I will find more categories than those 3 I've listed.

It's because I've seen you listed on the code the exact URL, I tought I could only list the categories, and then the script would find what URLs that contain that exact term.

Comment: Maybe first you can determine how many unique categories you will have by getting the unique url extensions and determining what those are.  You can get a unique records list by df['url_column'].unique() and see how many you have first.